# How to call a web service using C?

Tags: c, apache-axis, axis, axis2c

I downloaded Axis c++ and created a C stub. Now I have to call a web service. How to call a web service? Which method I should use? Does Axis C++ provide any sample code for that? Does any one here implemented it earlier, or can you guide with some code snippets to proceed further?

Comment: The page http://ws.apache.org/axis/cpp/index.html states the following, listed under features: "Soap engine with both client and server support" As SOAP is a webservice. I think Axis c++ should be able to handle webservices...

Comment: @Mike de Klerk Thanks for you reply..Ya I have downloaded it and created a stub file. Now I need to how to procced further and what is the method I should call to call the webservice.

Comment: Is it a SOAP / WSDL webservice ? I have no experience with any other webservice protocols. This tool will probably help you if it is a SOAP / WSDL service: http://ws.apache.org/axis/cpp/arch/WSDL2Ws.html as it will create skeleton classes based on a WSDL you provide.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk yes you are right! I have created a skeleton and I have a generated files in hand now ( thats what the C stub I have mentioned). What should be the nex step?

Comment: Well, probably the code skeleton of the webservice has created methods which can be invoked. Those will interact with the webservice when you call them, as you are the client in this case. Probably something like WebServiceResults r = WebServiceSkeleton.Method(Param A, Param b); and you can then process the service its feedback/results, which are stored in 'r' in this example.